# How to achieve nested activities gwt

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-activities

how to achieve nested activities in gwt. this is my use case.
[image]

i am attaching an activity mapper and Activity manager for each view. ie root,screen1,innerscreen. but i can see only the view upto screen1, the innerscreen is not displaying. how to handle this situation.
Please help me. thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you have read Thomas Broyers's [blog](http://blog.ltgt.net/gwt-21-activities-nesting-yagni/) about nested activities in GWT.

It seems your setup is alright since you are using as many activity managers as places in your screen. It is difficult to figure out the reason why the place3 is not being displayed, it seems like you are not setting correctly the display for the innerActivityManager, or maybe your mapper is not returning the appropriate activity.

Try to post some code or logs to figure out your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I did the nesting differently in my app:

I make visible or unvisible some root divs depending on the place (simply by setting a css styleName to the panel).

the only thing you have to do is to map special styles with a parameter in your place (ex: layout) if your place is mapped with a special style, you aplly it, else you put is back to the default one.

The trigger is in the PlaceController

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of places is that a place is your url, so you can have only one place. But for one place you can have many activities. Either you nest them or not is another question. If you want to nest them you can have a look to https://code.google.com/p/slotted/

If you do not want to nest have a look to Thomas Broyer article as mentioned by another answer.

By the way I tried to implement thomas broyer article, it is still a work in progress but you can have a look.

https://github.com/ronanquillevere/GWT-Multi-Activities